# Designing a python plugin system

Tags: python, plugins

I'm currently working on a system which processes a user specified list (in a file) of `metrics`; a metric is a collection of some strings and some logic as to how to perform a certain calculation. A python script is periodically run on a linux server and consults the file.

Metrics should be easily extensible, so I'm looking for some modular way to encapsulate the code for the calculation into the specification of a metric. In short of creating a config parsing system, which would severely limit the complexity of the calculations, I'm looking for a plugin system where the calculation of each metric can be specified in python code.

For example, here are the core units of a metric.

```
db = "database0"
mes = "measurement0"
tags = ["alpha", "beta", "delta"]
calculation: (accepts parameters a and b)
    for item in a:
        b.add(a)
    return b
```

The python script needs to grab each metric from file, access their string fields and execute their calculation code, passing the same parameters to each.

I currently have a terrible method; in a separate python file, I define a base class which is to be extended by each new metric. This is what it looks like

```
class Metric(object):
    def __init__(self, database_name, measurement_name, classad_tags, classad_fields=[]):
        """
        A specification of a metric.
        Arguments:
            database_name    - name of the influx DB (created if doesn't exist)
            measurement_name - measurement name with which to label metric in DB
            classad_tags     - list of classad fields (or mock ads) which will
                               segregate values at a time for this metric, becoming
                               tags in the influxDB measurement
            classad_fields   - any additional job classad fields that this metric will
                               look at (e.g. for metric value calculation).
                               These must be declared so that the daemon can fetch any
                               needed classads from condor
        """
        self.db = database_name
        self.mes = measurement_name
        self.tags = classad_tags
        self.fields = classad_fields

    def calculate_at_bin(self, time_bin, jobs):
        """
        """

        raise ReferenceError("")


"""
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""


class metric0(Metric):
    def __init__(self):

        db = 'testdb'
        mes = 'testmes0'
        tags = ['Owner']
        fields = []
        super(metric0, self).__init__(db, mes, tags, fields)

    def calculate_at_bin(self, time_bin, jobs):

        for job in jobs:
            if job.is_idle_during(time_bin.start_time, time_bin.end_time):
                time_bin.add_to_sum(1, job.get_values(self.tags))
        return time_bin.get_sum()
```

To create a new metric, you create a new subclass of `Metric`, passing the string fields to the super constructor and overriding the `calculate_at_bin` method. In the main python script, I create an instance of every metric with something like...

```
metrics = [metric() for metric in vars()['Metric'].__subclasses__()]
```

However, this is obviously terrible.
It involves things like completely arbitrary but requiredly unique subclass names (`metric0`) and code which isn't really relevant to the metric (e.g. class definitions, calling the constructor, etc).

I could imagine also another terrible method, like a config file with some code which gets `eval`'d, but I'd want to avoid that too.

Note that there are no concerns about security or code injection; this system will really only be used by a handful of people that I can instruct in person.
So; how should I go about this?

Comment: Having 'best practices' in a stackoverflow title leaves one vulnerable to drive-by downvotes

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making the code of a metric an importable module, offering a `calculate_at_bin` function as the "interface", place all such modules in a directory and then import them dynamically? Would remove the issues with the possible name clashes and if security is no concern it would be at least very simple to handle...

Comment: Are you suggesting each metric goes into a separate file and just creates some instance variables like db, mes.. and defines the calculate function? I think I want the metrics in a single file (and this seems just as dodgy and ad hoc; surely there's some elegant way to do this)

Comment: Each metric in it's own file and, when possible, share db etc. This would be easily extensible (add new module file, no modification, simple exception handling even on syntax errors), and the introspection (essentially a call to `os.listdir()` would be elegant. It is addressing all things you mentioned as terrible, too. Sorry for misunderstanding you.

Comment: I cannot have a file per metric unless they're all in a folder, which will face issues when extending (they'd need to all be added to .__init__). Not sure what you mean by "when possible, share db etc.". What do you mean I can do with `os.listdir()`? How can I use that to execute a python file in an isolated namespace?

Comment: Yes, all in a folder. And no, they do not have to be added to `__init__.py`. `os.listdir()` was meant to collect all the (metric-) modules from that folder. Sorry again, if that approach will not fit your needs. It was just a suggestion addressing the deficiencies listed in the question.

Comment: I think `os.listdir()` would allow you to do something like `execfile`, but will make those instance variables (`db`, etc) in global namespace, and won't be an "import". Also it doesn't "address all things mentioned as terrible" since crucially, the python file names are arbitrary and unused but required to be unique

Comment: Dynamic import with [importlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html). The naming wil be no issue because your file system makes sure that they are unique. Just saying.

Comment: The file names are still completely arbitrary and thus unintuitive. So to clarify, you're proposing using `os.lostdir()`, string manipulating the python module names to be able to import them with `importlib`? I'd like to believe there's a more elegant approach yet

Comment: Exactly. It is a super-simple and pragmatic approach that will need exactly 10 minutes to implement and you will never forget how to extend. But if you don't like it, it's fine for me. It was just a suggestion.